# Change of variables in integral is not working

Tags: matrix, numerical-value, numerical-integration

Consider the matrix

```
B = {{98.02629214676199`, -92.48048839972799`, 38.75630744234699`,
-7.871368221288002`, 0.6302470421610025`}, {-92.48048839972799`, 
136.78259958910897`, -100.351856621016`, 39.38655448450799`, -7.871368221288002`}, {38.75630744234699`, -100.351856621016`, 137.41284663126999`, -100.351856621016`, 38.75630744234699`}, {-7.871368221288002`, 39.38655448450799`, -100.351856621016`, 
136.78259958910897`, -92.48048839972799`}, {0.6302470421610025`,  -7.871368221288002`, 38.75630744234699`, -92.48048839972799`, 
98.02629214676199`}};
```

and the function

```
g[x_, y_, z_, r_, v_] := 1/(Pi^5*(1 + x^2)*(1 + y^2)*(1 + z^2)*(1 + r^2)*(1 + v^2));
```

The integral of $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^5$ is $1$:

```
NIntegrate[g[x, y, z, r, v], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, {r, -Infinity,Infinity}, {v, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* Output: 1 *)
```

Now we change of variables: $u=B\cdot (x,y,z,r,v)^T$ and $du=\det(B)\,dx\,dy\,dz\,dr\,dv$. The following integral should be $1$, because it is a change of variables:

```
NIntegrate[Apply[g, Inverse[B].{x, y, z, r, v}]*Det[Inverse[B]], {x,  -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, {r, -Infinity, Infinity}, {v, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* Output: 0.0376868 *)
```

What is happening here? Is this a problem of Mathematica's computations?

Comment: You changed the variables to u, but in your last NIntegrate the integration variables are unchanged x,y,...!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The formula for the change of variables is $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(\vec{x})d\vec{x}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(h(\vec{x}))Jh(\vec{x})d\vec{x}, $$ where $Jh$ is the Jacobian. Here, $h(\vec{x})=B\vec{x}$ and $Jh(\vec{x})=\det(B)$.

Comment: So I would expect the new variable u on the right side of your formula...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann $u$ is just a name: $h(x,y,z,r,v)=B\cdot (x,y,z,r,v)^T$. I am computing $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^5} g(h(x,y,z,r,v))Jh(x,y,z,r,v)\,dx\,dy\,dz\,dr\,dv=\int_{\mathbb{R}^5} g(B\cdot (x,y,z,r,v)^T)\det(B)\,dx\,dy\,dz\,dr\,dv$$by the change of variables formula that I wrote in the comment before. That should be $\int_{\mathbb{R}^5} g(x,y,z,r,v)\,dx\,dy\,dz\,dr\,dv=1$.

Comment: Your naming is risky, but I can handle it. I think the substitution you made in your last integral is wrong. Instead of  `g[u[[1]], u[[2]], u[[3]], u[[4]], u[[5]]]` you should use `Apply[g, Inverse[B].{x, y, z, r, v}]` because g is defined as a function of x,y,...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You're right. Thank you very much. I edited the question.

Comment: There is a very small factor (`2.84446*10^-11`) in the  transposed integrand, which  NIntegrate can't handle .

Comment: @UlrichNeumann What is the "transposed integrand"?

Comment: `Apply[g, Inverse[B].{x, y, z, r, v}]*Det[Inverse[B]]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann So Mathematica is not computing correctly Apply[g, Inverse[B].{x, y, z, r, v}]*Det[Inverse[B]], right? Is this happening because of bad properties of $B$? Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Mathematica computes numerical, so the scaling of the transformation B is not optimal.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Is there any change I could do in the code to solve this problem and obtain $1$ as the integral?

Comment: What's the purpose of the transformation, where does B come from?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I have a random vector with density function given by $g$. I am doing a transformation of my random vector with the matrix $B$, and to check that everything works, I need to ensure that NIntegrate[Apply[g, Inverse[B].{x, y, z, r, v}]*Det[Inverse[B]], {x,  -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, {r, -Infinity, Infinity}, {v, -Infinity, Infinity}] is $1$.

Comment: One way to solve your problem is to use the option `WorkingPrecision->25`inside NIntegrate. Doing so an error occurs `The precision of the argument functioni sless than 25... ` , probably the precision of B is to small.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann If I write NIntegrate[Apply[g, Inverse[B].{x, y, z, r, v}]*Det[Inverse[B]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, {r, -Infinity, Infinity}, {v, -Infinity, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 25], I obtain a similar result: 0.03768680903930362052180464. I do not know how to obtain $1$.

Comment: Again my question: Where does B come from? Is it possible to increase the precision of B?